# I can't use my Huawei modem in Ubuntu 16.10

Tags: 16.10, usb-modem, modem, huawei, modem-manager

After installing Ubuntu 16.10, I've created a mobile broadband connection, but, for some reasons, the connection can`t be displayed. Help me to solve this problem!

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Ubuntu Gnome 16.10, tried lots of suggestions found over the web on forums but the only thing that did work was upgrading `usb-modeswitch` package found on Debian Sid repositories, links bellow chose according to your architecture.

- [`usb-modeswitch_2.4.0+repack0-1_amd64.deb`](http://ftp.pt.debian.org/debian/pool/main/u/usb-modeswitch/usb-modeswitch_2.4.0+repack0-1_amd64.deb)
- [`usb-modeswitch_2.4.0+repack0-1_i386.deb`](http://ftp.pt.debian.org/debian/pool/main/u/usb-modeswitch/usb-modeswitch_2.4.0+repack0-1_i386.deb)
- [`usb-modeswitch-data_20160803-1_all.deb`](http://ftp.pt.debian.org/debian/pool/main/u/usb-modeswitch-data/usb-modeswitch-data_20160803-1_all.deb)

If your USB dongle is activated via PIN than disable it otherwise you'll have to run `nm-applet` on console in order to have a PIN request dialog box, due to changes on `network-manager`, you can close it afterward.